# Using utf8mb4 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-5.6, utf8mb4

In order to use 4-byte `utf8mb4` in MySQL (5.6.11), I have set the following variables in the `my.ini` file (`my.cnf` is not found). This file is located in a hidden folder named `Application Data` (`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`) on Windows XP. It is not available under the installation directory.

```
[client]
port=3306
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

And then issuing the following command,

```
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE Variable_name
LIKE 'character\_set\_%'
OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

still displays the following list.

[image]

From the picture itself, it is clear that several variables are still using 3-byte `utf8`.

---

Before doing this, the following command had already been issued to make corresponding changes to the database itself.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And the following command had also been issued on each and every table in the said database.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

---

Nevertheless, what is the reason why some variables have not yet been set to the said character set as well as the collation? What is missing?

The system (operating system) itself was restarted after every single task specified above had been carried out.

Comment: Be warned:  user=root (or other SUPER user) will not execute `init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *client* usually sets these values when connecting. The settings in my.ini are merely defaults which apply when the client does not explicitly specify a connection encoding. Since they're unreliable, every client *should* specify a connection encoding. Since you've got some fancy screenshot there I'll guess that you're connecting with some GUI utility which probably explicitly *does* set some connection encodings.

PHP example of setting a connection charset:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4')
```

Comment: So, are they basically not to be worried about? I created a connection pool from Java side where some parameters have been set such as `characterEncoding` is set to `UTF-8`, `useUnicode` to `true` and `characterSetResults` to `UTF-8`. They basically serve the purpose of the parameters which are appended to a connection string with the same name/value pair. (The screenshot was taken from MySQL WorkBench. MySQL terminal has not been opening for some unclear reasons, since MySQL was installed. It just flashes out for a while and disappears, when `mysql.exe` is double clicked. So, I use WorkBench)

Comment: If your actual client is going to declare its own `utf8mb4` connection encoding, then yes, it's not to be worried about. You don't need to touch my.ini at all to get a utf8mb4 workflow going.

Comment: I could manage to start MySQL command-line somehow. It only sets those values to `utf8mb4`, when `skip-character-set-client-handshake` is used. On MySQL WorkBench, it requires a manual command `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';` to be issued which turns all of those values into `utf8mb4` but still leaves `collation_connection` to its value `utf8mb4_general_ci`. `character_set_system` on the other hand, remains stationary in all the cases to `utf8`.

Comment: @Tiny any way to configure Mysql Workbench to to use utf8mb4 by default so issuing SET names utf8mb4 isn't necessary each time I connect?

Answer (score 6):

If you show your global variables, you might see that all your settings are correct actually.

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

This might be related to this [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74680) 
I also faced the same problem in the past. I changed a DB charset from utf8 to utf8mb4. Executing queries directly from mysql command line was ok but I had problem inserting emojis with Workbench. I ended up setting it manually by running

`SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`

every time I open a connection to my DB with Workbench.

Using **Sequel Pro** as alternative was fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are connecting as root, hence the `init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'` is not executed.

It is unwise to use root (or SUPER) for any application code; just for administrative actions.

Comment: I nowhere read, "*It is unwise to use root (or SUPER) for any application code*". I interpreted "*application code*" as client applications such as  Java/PHP/ASP.NET or something else. Does it meant that one should always insist upon creating another/other user/s, if one wishes to use MySQL through client applications which should access database/s from that another user and not from the root user?

Comment: It is a general security issue.  If a hacker can get into a client and discover the root password, then he can destroy not only the database, but possibly the machine it is on.  And, if you have multiple users, it is better to do some amount of isolation between them.  By _application code_ I mean both end users (who generally should not have mysql login at all) and app layers (Java, etc) that act on their behalf.

Comment: And, perhaps, you found the little-known caveat about `root` skipping `init-connect`?

Comment: `utf8mb4` appears to be set, when `skip-character-set-client-handshake` is used. I do not even know what it means (I think its usage is discouraged). RDBMS is something which is far beyond me :)

Answer (score -1):

On win7

1. use "win + R" and type "services.msc"
2. find service of mysql
3. check the file path. It will tell you where the my.ini
4. open and add some properties:

   [client]
   default-character-set = utf8mb4

   [mysql]
   default-character-set = utf8mb4

   [mysqld]
   character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
   character-set-server = utf8mb4
   collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
5. restart the mysql service