# c# Having trouble with mysql : Incorrect string value code 1366 for column at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8

> ERROR C# MVC5 using ADO.NET when update columns using Chinese in mysql(version:5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)):
>       {"Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE6\x96\x87' for column 'Title_1' at row 1"}

I have already tried charset for database, table and columns.

```
(1)'utf8' 'utf8_general_ci'
(2)'utf8' 'utf8_unicode_ci'
(3)'utf8mb4' 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
(4)'utf8mb4' 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Also,I've added charset=utf8mb4 or charset=utf8 in connectionstring in Web.config

my connection string is

> `<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;port=3306;Initial Catalog=jn001;User Id=Userid;password=Password;charset=utf8mb4">`

Google all day finding answers,
Still can't find a solution,
Please tell me a solution,Thanks!

[here is my mysql charset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Jxq.png)

---

I've followed LocEngineer's advertisement and set mysql server to utf8mb4

[here is my new mysql charset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev8lY.png)

[And this is my collation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsoFG.png)

All change to utf8mb4 (including connectionstring) ,but still the same error occur.

Anyway ,thanks for the suggestions.

------------------------------9/5update--------------------------------

[my SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Kcr.png%60%60%60)

```
 public bool UpdateDetails(Class1 content)
        {
            connection();
            MySqlCommand cmdSet = new MySqlCommand("set names utf8mb4", con);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title_1",content.Title_1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title_2", content.Title_2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title_3", content.Title_3);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content_1", content.Content_1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content_2", content.Content_2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content_3", content.Content_3);

            con.Open();
            cmdSet.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

this is mysql update Procedure

```
UPDATE Stop_Info SET Title_1 = Title_1,Title_2=Title_2,Title_3=Title_3,Content_1=Content_1,Content_2=Content_2,Content_3=Content_3 WHERE Pkey = 3
```

HTML form accept-charset="utf-8"

```
<form id="registerForm" method="post" action="~/Home/Index" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Did you specify the useUnicode in your connection string ? --> ```useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8```

Comment: here is my connection string , <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;port=3306;Initial Catalog=jn001;User Id=Userid;password=Password@;charset=utf8"/>

Comment: Olivier Depriester {"Option not supported.\r\n: useunicode"} seems like useUnicode error

Comment: Sorry, I gave you jdbc connection string parameters. They do not apply to c#

Comment: It seems that utf8 is a bit of a misnomer in mySql. You need to use utf8mb4, both in your database but also in your connection string. Check out https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540772/using-utf8mb4-in-mysql .

Comment: LocEngineer  thanks, i've tried and update my situation, still problem can't be solved

Comment: Please show your current connection string. I have found an almost identical issue (solved) here: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1811 . Look at the connection string used in the very last entry of that thread.

Comment: I'll try this thank you

Comment: LocEngineer <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;port=3306;Initial Catalog=jn001;User Id=Userid;password=Password;charset=utf8mb4">

Comment: Have you  also performed for each database: `ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`  For each table: `ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`  For each column: `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`  ?

Comment: yes,but still same problem, i've update some code above,please check it

Comment: Problem been solved ,it's my PROSEDURE problem , thanks for you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE6\x96\x87` is hex for `中文` ("Chinese language").

In MySQL, this will work with either `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.  However, since there are several Chinese characters that need 4 bytes, you are correct to use utf8mb4.  Meanwhile, the `COLLATION` (eg, utf8mb4_unicode_ci) does not matter to the Question in hand.

The individual column's charset is important, not the database's.  And the 191 kludge is needed only in 5.5 and 5.6.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Another way to establish the connection parameters is to issue `SET NAMES utf8mb4` immediately after connecting.  (This is not preferred, but might be worth trying. 
 It should be a workaround for the Gorm issue mentioned.)

Are you getting the error message when connecting?  Or when issuing a particular query?  If so, please provide that query.

Check that `skip-character-set-client-handshake` is not being used.

Check the "Best practice" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831

**Addenda**  Since you mentioned a stored procedure, I suggest you do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` to see what charset it was built with.  Here's an example of what can happen:

```
mysql> SET NAMES latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE x () BEGIN END ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE x \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Procedure: x
            sql_mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    Create Procedure: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `x`()
BEGIN END
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE x;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

versus:

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE x () BEGIN END ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE x \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Procedure: x
            sql_mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    Create Procedure: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `x`()
BEGIN END
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't see utf8mb4 on your `PROCEDURE` and `FUNCTION` declarations, rebuild them.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late, I've update SHOW CREATE TABLE and some code , please check my content above.

Comment: I've tried the link and made some change to my code,can't still solve the problem

Comment: @jimmyan - Stored Proc was the clue I needed.  See my Addenda.

Comment: OMG! I'm so dumb , forget to change utf8 in my PROCEDURE. I've solved the problem!! Thanks for reminding , saving my day.

Comment: @jimmyan - You are welcome.  (And click the check mark.)

Answer (score 0):

This didnt work for me. After days of fiddling and trying practically everything, I had to add charset utf8mb4 to the parameter declaration in the stored proc. param text charset utf8mb4.