# Clarifications needed about SET NAMES instruction and character_set variables

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

Recently, i had the need to store emoji in some of the table in my DB (MySQL / MariaDB), so after a bit of research i've found out that the encoding i was using (UTF8) wasn't enough and i needed to move to UTF8-mb4.
I then changed the charset of the table i needed to the new encoding, but clearly it wasn't enough. I changed also my connection string i use when creating a new [DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-6.0), specifying the encoding utf8mb4, and still i couldn't manage to save emojy.
Finally i've found this answer [Using utf8mb4 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540772/using-utf8mb4-in-mysql) , which suggested the use of `SET NAMES` instruction.
This solved my problem, but i noticed that the instruction was active until i restarted the db service.
I would like to know:

1. which exactly is the effect of using `SET NAMES` instruction, especially for the tables that are using the old utf8 encoding?
2. which is the proper way to use it? (In my.ini or in my code?)
3. Is there anything i need to worry about this instruction?
4. Are there other ways to set character_set_client and character_set_connection to utf8mb4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The effect of the `SET NAMES` command is specified in [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html): it sets these three system variables to the specified value:

- [character_set_client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client)
- [character_set_connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection)
- [character_set_results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results)

It can't have any effect on tables using the old `utf8` collation, as emoji cannot be stored in that encoding; the data is lost. For new tables, it may have an effect on how the server interprets string literals your client sends (`character_set_connection`) and how emoji retrieved from the table are sent back to the client (`character_set_results`).

2. You should never need to use it explicitly in your code. A correct client library will set this value for you, both via the handshake response packet that the client sends, and as needed if the server ever switches to a different character set for the connection. [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) has the correct behaviour in this regard and I would recommend switching to it. (Disclaimer: lead author)
3. No, let your client library take care of it for you.
4. Yes, in the [handshake response packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeResponse), but this is an implementation detail of the client library you're using. You can also set them with a statement like `SET @@character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4';`.